# Still receiving division by zero error when using CAST FLOAT64

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

EDIT: I have changed the title after some experimentation.
I am using Standard SQL in BigQuery and get division by zero error when attempting to divide using CAST()

Reservations Table Schema:

> Flat STRING   NULLABLE
> pay_day DATE    NULLABLE    %E4Y/%m/%d
> USD_amt INTEGER NULLABLE
> EANR    STRING  NULLABLE

I can do the following query:

```
SELECT Flat, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pay_day) AS Yr, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EANR='Cancelled' THEN USD_amt END) AS Cancel_rev,
SUM(USD_amt)AS Yr_rev
GROUP BY Flat, Yr
ORDER BY 1
```

Which outputs fine:

```
Row Flat    Yr  Yr_rev  cancel_rev
1   null    null    null    null
2   1   2018    1994    null
3   1   2019    29709   100
4   1   2020    13588   5212
5   1A  2020    4432    null
6   1A  2021    0   null
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
Flat    Yr  Yr_rev  Cancel_rev  % revenue
                
1   2018    1994                  0.00%
1   2019    29709   100           0.34%
1   2020    13588   5212          38.36%
1A  2020    3767    2             0.05%
2   2019    10857   2             0.02%
2   2020    13890   4223          30.40%
2   2021    1014                  0.00%
3   2019    7965    233           2.93%
3   2020    18333   4143          22.60%
3   2021    10736                 0.00%
4   2020    0                     0.00%
```

But I cannot divide Cancel_rev / Yr_rev to get Cancel_rev_% using the below, i receive the error "division by zero: 0 / 0"

```
SUM(CASE WHEN EANR='Cancelled' THEN CAST(USD_amt AS FLOAT64) END)/SUM(CAST(USD_amt AS FLOAT64)) AS Cancel_Rev_Perc
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, it seems this is due to a combination of USD_amt being an integer
and division with NULL values. it works now if I use the feature   SAFE_DIVIDE()

```
SAFE_DIVIDE((SUM(CASE WHEN EANR='Cancelled' THEN USD_amt END)),(SUM(USD_amt))) as Cancel_rev_Perc
```

Answer (score -1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Use window functions!

```
SELECT Flat, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pay_day) AS Year, 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN EANR = 'Cancelled' THEN USD_amt END) /
        SUM(SUM(USD_amt)) OVER (PARTITION BY Flat, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pay_day))
       ) AS Cancel_ratio
FROM `finances.reservations`
GROUP BY Flat, Year
ORDER BY 1;
```

In BigQuery, you can use a subquery to define the alias:

```
SELECT Flat, Year, 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN EANR = 'Cancelled' THEN USD_amt END) /
        SUM(SUM(USD_amt)) OVER (PARTITION BY Flat, YEAR)
       ) AS Cancel_ratio
FROM (SELECT r.*, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pay_day) AS Year
      FROM `finances.reservations` r
     ) r
GROUP BY Flat, Year
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: This results in the following error: "PARTITION BY expression references column pay_day which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3]

Comment: @Bran . . . Depending on the database you are using, you might be able to use `year` there instead.  You haven't specified the database.

Comment: I said it in the title, standard SQL being used in BigQuery

Comment: After some experimenting, it seems this is due to USD_amt being an integer, I have posted the code and error and changed title accordingly. Thank you for your suggestion